# How to figure out the moduleID from a React Native Project

Tags: react-native

React-native replaces the module name with a ID.

```
Original
var _react = require('react');
Final Version
var _react = require(12);
```

How to figure out the module ID?

I want to have access to map that bind the name with a ID. 
I don't want to access the final bundle file and figure out the ID. Instead I want to use the map that the packager generates.

Comment: I'm guessing that the ID is related to the mapping done by http://localhost:8081/index.ios.map?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false
but I'm not sure.

Comment: What kind of wrong decision has taken you to this point?

Comment: I'm working on the core of the react native. It's not a simple application. I'm basically embedding on react native application inside another react native application. This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960415/remotely-update-a-single-file-from-a-project maybe explain better what I'm planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native contains a packager (React Native Packager) that is responsible for bundling and mapping.

When running your application on debug mode, you have two alternatives:

DEVELOPMENT MODE:
http://localhost:8081/index.ios.map?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=true

RELEASE MODE:
http://localhost:8081/index.ios.map?platform=ios&dev=false&minify=true

Obvious I'm assuming that you are using the port 8081 for your NPM server.

This link gives you a .JSON file. The JSON file contains an attribute named "sections". Each session has a attribute "map" and then an attribute "sources".

**JSON Example**

```
{"version":3,"file":"/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=true","sections":[{"offset":{"line":0,"column":0},"map":{"version":3,"sources":["/Users/oximer/Documents/myproject/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/prelude_dev.js"],"names":["global","__DEV__","__BUNDLE_START_TIME__","Date","now"],"mappings":"CAAA,SAAAA,GAaAA,EAAOC,SAAU,EAEjBD,EAAOE,sBAAwBC,KAAKC"}}]}
```

The packager goes through this JSON file and it results in a map (filename,/position on array). It basically replaces the string on required by the position on the array.

Resulting on

> require(prelude_dev)

being replaced by

> require(1)

.